# How can I rename my visual studio taskbar button?

Tags: visual-studio, autohotkey

I often work with multiple checkouts of the same solution, but as they all have the same name, all the taskbar buttons appear the same.  I would like to rename the taskbar buttons so I can identify solutions more easily.

I have written an autohotkey script, which almost works, or if anyone can suggest something better, I'd like to hear it.

This works on an explorer window, but fails on almost everything else.

```
#f2::
InputBox NewName, Rename Window, Enter a new name for this window:
WinGet CurrentWindow, ID, A
WinSetTitle, ahk_id %CurrentWindow%, , %NewName%
return
```

One possibility is that other windows rename themselves every frame.  Putting the code in an infinite loop means that I can now rename Notepad2 windows (but not visual studio windows), but I can only run the script once!

Comment: good question - I'd like to see the answer to this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the solution in solution explorer. Don't commit into source control!